# What if my changes in .css file are not reflected in output of my project?

Tags: css

I have done some minor changes like color and size like changes in my project.
But when I save it and run it, the change is not reflected in the output of the program.
I tried refreshing the server, even tried restarting eclipse, but none of these worked..
Please help..

Comment: try to clear browser cache.. like you can get clear cache addon for firefox

Comment: you can also use private browsing

Comment: Clear browser cache, and check if style is not overridden.

Comment: Open the css files in your browser that is linked to the html you are viewing (view source and click on the link in the <head><link> )and see if your changes are present. If they are not, you may have uploaded it wrongly

Comment: i have already ran the css file and seen it, the changes are not even reflected in the css file..

Answer (score 0):

Remove all your browser cache, generally its the issue of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different browser or different computer. If problem persists, the css is not really there or is being overrriden.

Use tools like 'inspect element' or 'web developer' to troubleshoot the viewed page.

Comment: I have already used inspect element, the change is reflected in inspect element, but if I run the css file, it does not even have altered the changes I have done..